# Increasing progress bar value by decimal value and few more problems in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

I have following problems.

A) How can i increase value of progress bar by decimal values? I tried

`ui->progressBar->setValue(0.5);` and increased this using while loop by added 0.5.
But all I got is empty progress bar. Any idea why?

p.s:I got warning 'This statement has no effect' on the line `ui->progressBar->setValue(0.5);`

B)  While making a progress bar I made a while loop with progress bar value increments by 1 and added Sleep(600) so that progress bar doesn't complete very fast. That isn't the problem, my problem is while the progress bar is increasing, my app lags a lot. I tried putting `QCoreApplication::processEvents();` all over my while loop and all over in my code but that didn't work. What to do?

Comment: Are you sure the 'This statement has no effect' is due to setting the value of the progress bar?  Perhaps you had a while loop immediately above it with a semi-colon on the end of the while loop?

Answer (score 3):

`QProgressBar::setValue` takes an `int` parameter. `0.5` converted to `int` is `0`, as any fule kno. So you are effectively calling `setValue (0)`.

To do this properly, you have to call `setMinimum` and `setMaximum`, and then scale the floating-point number by the appropriate factor.

But I must confess, I'm puzzled by your "statement has no effect" warning. Are you sure about that?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding B), do not use Sleep in the main thread.  Of course this will make your application unresponsive, because no repaints or input event handling can occur while the thread is sleeping.  Instead use a `QTimer` connected to a slot which increments your progress bar value.

Comment: There's some example code at http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Archived:QTimer_example which should point you in the right direction.  I would also recommend reading the Qt documentation to learn how signals and slots work.